# Does EF6 silently execute Expressions it can't convert client side?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We are porting an existing application from EF6 to EF Core 3.1. In the process of doing so, we came across a situation in which a query that was previously working now fails at runtime because it contains an `Expression` that can't be translated.

```
public class Task : SqlUserUpdatableSequenceBase
{
    ...

    public override Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetSameSequencePredicate<TEntity>()
        => entity => (entity as Task).ProjectId == ProjectId;

    ...
}
```

```
private List<ItemSequence> UpdateSequenceInternal<TEntity>(TEntity entity, ItemSequence sequence)
            where TEntity : SqlUserUpdatableSequenceBase
        {
           ...

            var query = Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
            query = query.Where(entity.GetSameSequencePredicate<TEntity>());

           ...
        }
```

So it seems that the cast `(entity as Task)` in the Expression is what cannot be translated by EF Core.

I know this behavior of failing when an Expression can't be translated is [listed as one of the breaking changes with mayor impact.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client) However, the documentation talks about it in relation to previous versions of EF Core, not EF 6.

> Before 3.0, **when EF Core** couldn't convert an expression that was part of a query to either SQL or a parameter, it automatically evaluated the expression on the client. By default, client evaluation of potentially expensive expressions only triggered a warning.

I have figured out some workarounds to solve this issue, but I am still wondering if **EF 6 was able to translate this expression to SQL or was it also silently executing it client side?**

Comment: I don't believe so, but EF Core has had SEVERAL deviations in implementation from what EF6 could provide, either in the "too hard", "no one should be doing anyway" or "not interesting/new, so might get to that eventually" buckets.  My guess would be the issue lies in `(entity as Task).ProjectId` where EFCore doesn't trust the casting where EF6 would be happy to try and assume it would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the input @StevePy :) I wish there was some more documentation stating the breaking changes between EF6 and EFCore

Comment: It would change weekly. :)  I've dabbled with EF Core but frankly I stick with EF6. It has reliable documentation & performance. IMHO open sourcing EF was a blunder. Great in theory, but rarely great in practice.